# Crash at creating Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, crash

I have some problem at changing to a separate activity in my app.
The called activity is added to the manifest, so this  isn't the problem (would have been too easy, right?)

This is my main activity, that calls the troublesome activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}

public void onBtnClick(final View view) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_Start:
        ...//Working fine
        break;
    case R.id.btn_Options:
        ...//Also working
        break;
    case R.id.btn_Highscores:
        intent = new Intent(this, ScoresMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

And this is the called activity:

```
public class ScoresMenu extends Activity {

String[] content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores_menu);

    MyDB db = new MyDB(this);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Scores);

    content = db.getScores(); 
    //This returns a String[20], currently with one entry at [0]

    ArrayAdapter<String> scoreList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content);
    lv.setAdapter(scoreList);
    db.close();
}
}
```

Here is the requested getScores():

```
public String[] getScores() { 

String[] scoreList = new String[20];

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_SCORES, 
                new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_X, KEY_Y, KEY_A, KEY_TIME}, 
                null, null, null, null, 
                KEY_TIME + " ASC", 
                null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    int i = 1; 
    do { 
        String score; 
        String name = cursor.getString(1); 
        int x = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(2)); 
        int y = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(3)); 
        int a = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(4)); 
        String t = cursor.getString(5);

        if(i < 10) 
            score = "0" + i; 
        else 
            score = "" + i; score = score + ") " + name + " (" + x + "x" + y + " Felder mit " + a + " Minen in " + t + ")";

            scoreList[i] = score; i++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
}
cursor.close(); 
return scoreList; 
} 
}
```

With LogCat I chased the problem so far, that everything runs till past "lv.setAdapter(scoreList);". So I guess there is some error, populating the ListView with the scoreList...

LogCat itself gives me the following:

```
03-30 19:04:12.289: W/dalvikvm(9014): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d7d8a8)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2340)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1638)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2170)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13846)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4466)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2156)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4616)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:747)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:567)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:536)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:733)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-30 19:04:15.221: E/AndroidRuntime(9014):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 19:04:15.257: I/Process(9014): Sending signal. PID: 9014 SIG: 9
```

Can anyone figure out the Problem here?

Comment: Are you sure your content array is not null?  Print it out.  Make sure that content = db.getScores(); is returning what you expect.

Comment: have you open close your database!

Comment: show us the code which runs in your mydb class, that's most likely the source of the error.

Comment: Double checked, db was closed.
Also the Content seems to be passed over, but not written to the right place... searching for the reason atm.

Comment: I added the code of getScores() to OP

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in 'content' passed to ArrayAdapter.

- Try logging the content variable and see if it has the expected value
- Check if the open() method of 'db' is called